# Jsf 2.0 Populate h:selectOneMenu to access page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am newbie in JSF 2.0, I worked in JSF 1.1 and 1.2 and I populate selectOneMenu in constructor of Managed bean's page. For when users to acces to page the List is populate. example below. I put the same in JSF 2.0 but is not work, the selectOneMenu appears empty.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="cboStatus" value="#{PersonBean.idStatus}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{PersonBean.status}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In constructor's managed bean I put:

```
public class PersonBean {    
    private SelectItem[] status=new SelectItem[0];

    public PersonBean () {
        detallePersonas= new ArrayList();

 status= new SelectItem[3];
 status[0]=new SelectItem("S","Single");
 status[1]=new SelectItem("M","Married");
 status[2]=new SelectItem("D","Divorced");
    }
}
```

1. Editor Netbeans 6.8 (JSF 2.0 default configuration wizard)
2. No Exception Error
3. Never run the constructor PersonBean (I put a breakpoint and never stops)
4. There are other ways to populate selects to load the page

This is the complete code:

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Person</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="frmPerson">
            <h:outputLabel id="lblStatus" value="Status:"/>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="cboStatus" value="#{PersonBean.idStatus}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{PersonBean.status}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**PersonBean.java**

```
package com.prueba.backingbean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrador
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "Person")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonBean {

    private String idStatus;
    private SelectItem[] status = new SelectItem[0];

    public PersonBean() {
        status = new SelectItem[3];
        status[0] = new SelectItem("S", "Single");
        status[1] = new SelectItem("M", "Married");
        status[2] = new SelectItem("D", "Divorced");
    }

    /**
     * @return the idStatus
     */
    public String getIdStatus() {
        return idStatus;
    }

    /**
     * @param idStatus the idStatus to set
     */
    public void setIdStatus(String idStatus) {
        this.idStatus = idStatus;
    }

    /**
     * @return the status
     */
    public SelectItem[] getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * @param status the status to set
     */
    public void setStatus(SelectItem[] status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "Person")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonBean {
```

You've declared the managed bean name as `Person`. So it's in JSF EL available as `#{Person}`. Yet you're attempting to access it as `#{PersonBean}`. Because such a bean does not exist, the menu remains empty.

You've 3 options:

1. Rename `#{PersonBean}` by `#{Person}` in your JSF page.
2. Rename `@ManagedBean(name = "Person")` to `@ManagedBean(name = "PersonBean")` in your managed bean.
3. Get rid of bean name and use the default JSF naming conventions. I.e. just use `@ManagedBean` without a `name` and use `#{personBean}` in your JSF page (in essence, the bean's class name with first character lowercased).

Option 3 is preferred.

Comment: Ok is working right now. Thank you all. especially to BalusC.

Answer (score 2):

```
          private Map<String,String>status = new HashMap<String,String>();
          .......
          status.put("S", "Single");
          status.put("M", "Married");
          status.put("D", "Divorced");
```

in JSF PAGE:

```
         <h:selectOneMenu value="#{personBean.idStatus}"  >

            <f:selectItems value="#{personBean.status}"/>                

         </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be "personBean" instead of "PersonBean" (first letter should be lowercase). You also need getter for status (`getStatus()`) and setter/getter for idStatus (`setIdStatus()`/`getIdStatus()`). Are they there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using List instead of Array of SelectItems.
Below code might help you.

```
private List<SelectItem> status = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

status.add(new SelectItem("S","Single"));
status.add(new SelectItem("M","Married"));
status.add(new SelectItem("D","Divorced"));

/*
     SETTER / GETTER
*/
```

Comment: Nope, both ways are equally valid.